# wanting to add an age gate to my quiz

Tags: python

hi there what i've tried a lot is to make it so at the start of the quiz it asks the user there age. if the user is under 5 they will only be asked 5 questions and if there over 5 they will be asked all 10

```
  #rhys translation quiz
#the list of questions that will be asked
question_list = [
(   "What is Kia ora in english",
    "a. Hello\nb. Bye\nc. Greetings\nd. See ya\n",
    "a"),
(   "What is tena rawa atu koe in english",
    "a. Give it\nb. bye\nc. Thank you\nd. See ya\n",
    "c"),
(   "What is rorohiko in english",
    "a. TV\nb. Microwave\nc. Oven\nd. Computer\n",
    "d"),
(   "What is taraka in english",
    "a. Van\nb. Car\nc. Truck\nd. bus\n",
    "c"),
(   "What is kāri in english",
    "a. Deck\nb. Game\nc. Suit\nd. Card\n",
    "d"),
(   "What is kai in english",
    "a. Food\nb. Drink\nc. Soup\nd. Water\n",
    "a"),
(   "What is kiriata in english",
    "a. Show\nb. Film\nc. Song\nd. Book\n",
    "b"),
(   "What is makawe in english",
    "a. Face\nb. Hair\nc. Neck\nd. Beard\n",
    "b"),
(   "What is tau in english",
    "a. Letter\nb. Number\nc. Space\nd. Shape\n",
    "b"),
(   "What is wini in english",
    "a. Win\nb. Lose\nc. Try again\nd. Quit\n",
    "a"),
]
play_again = True
while play_again:
    score = 0
    #intro and instruction  
    print ("""Welcome to the translation quiz")
age = int(input("Please enter your age: ))
print("You will be ask a series of questions and have 2 tries per questions
If you get the correct answer you will get one point, half a point for getting it
your second try and zero points if you get it wrong twice.
GOOD LUCK!!! """)

counter = 0
for question, options, correct in question_list:
    print(question)
    print(options)
    if counter == 5 and age <= 5:
        break

    counter +=1
        #user will have to enter a,b,c or d for there answer
    response = input("Hit 'a', 'b', 'c' or 'd' for your answer\n")
        #simple, if answer is correct print correct and move on to next question, if not try again
    if response.lower() == correct:
            print ("Correct\n")
            score = score + 1
            #this will say there wrong and they will get another try. if they get it right they get 0.5 points and if not they move on to the next question
    else:
            print("Wrong. Try again.\n")
            response = input("Hit 'a', 'b', 'c' or 'd' for your answer\n")
            if response.lower() == correct:
                print ("Correct\n")
                score = score + 0.5
            else:
                print("Wrong. You ran out of attempts\n")
                #this will print the users final score out of 10
    print ("Your score was", str (score)+"/10")
    #this is a restart. if the user says y then they restart if not the program ends.
    response = input("Do you want to play again (y/n)?").strip().lower()
    if response not in ('', 'y', 'yes'):
        play_again = False
```

Comment: I don't see anything in your code at all about the user's age.

Comment: sorry i mean as you can see the quiz asked the user 10 questions. But what i've tried to do is make it so at the start of the quiz it asked the user what age they are. if the user is under 5 it will only ask them 5 of the 10 questions but if their over 5 it will asked them all 10.

Comment: Great; please include your attempts. There's no need to repeat your description of the feature you're working on.

Comment: ok well i wasn't sure exactly how to do it but this is what i tried. age = input (what is your age)
if age = <5
    print(question)
    print(options)

Comment: Remember to edit the question rather than posting the age-related code in a comment.

Comment: i wasn't sure if i need to create a new list called question_list 2 with only 5 questions or something. sorry im still learning coding

Comment: thanks still learning how to use this website but i've added the code i tried just after the instructions part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of ways in which you could accomplish this. First of all you need to ask the user their age. So there must be an input function somewhere. Personally, I would put it here:

```
while play_again:
    score = 0
    #intro and instruction  
    print ("""Welcome to the translation quiz...""")
    #new input function here. You can make the message more or less formal
    age = int(input("Please enter your age: ))
```

Now quite honestly I would change around your for loop... Its a bit wonky. Instead of unpacking all the values of the tuple I would simply iterate over each individual tuple and then index the tuple (Since you know that the data order will always be Question->choices->answer).

That would make the 'age problem' easier. The most immediate way that I can think of is to use an if statement + a range() iterable. Note: this piece comes after the while loop. Like this:

```
#Set a default value.. saves us an extra else clause
number_questions = 10
if age <= 5:
    number_questions = 5

#range() will generate a list from 0->number_questions - 1




 #the -1 bit is crucial, if you do not anticipate that it will screw up some of your loops. 
#The idea is that everything should be base 0, so a programmer can quickly write range(len(some_generic_list)) and have it iterate through the indexes of the list.
#Anyhow I digress but you said you are new at programming so I thought I would be informative... 


for question in range(0,number_questions):
    print(question_list[question][0])
    print(question_list[question][1])

    print("Question Instructions........")
```

or another way is to set up a simple counter variable. Like this:

```
counter = 0
for question, options, correct in question_list:
    print(question)
    print(options)
    if counter == 5 and age <= 5:
     #if you reach the 5th question then you want to break the for loop.
        break

    #increment the variable to keep track of position
    counter +=1
```

After some thought I think the latter is more fitting with the code layout which you have provided so therefore "better". Additionally its uses the least lines of code so in this case simpler. But I am a stickler for(no pun intended) range iterables and indexing so.... I guess its personal choice at that point. With only 10 questions performance nor memory usage truly matters.

EDIT: After some bug hunting and tweaking the best version (and fully working) is as follows:

```
play_again = True
while play_again:
    score = 0
    counter = 0

    #intro and instruction
    print ("""Welcome to the translation quiz""")
    print("""You will be ask a series of questions and have 2 tries per questions
    If you get the correct answer you will get one point, half a point for getting it
    your second try and zero points if you get it wrong twice.
    GOOD LUCK!!! """)

    age = int(input("Please enter your age: "))
    for question, options, correct in question_list:
        if counter == 5 and age <= 5:
            break
        else:
            print(question)
            print(options)
            ans = input("Hit 'a', 'b', 'c' or 'd' for your answer\n")
            if ans.lower() == correct:
                    print ("Correct\n")
                    score += 1
            else:
                    print("Wrong. Try again.\n")
                    ans = input("Hit 'a', 'b', 'c' or 'd' for your answer\n")
                    if ans.lower() == correct:
                        print ("Correct\n")
                        score += 0.5
                    else:
                        print("Wrong. You ran out of attempts\n")

        counter += 1


    print ("Your score was", str(score) + '/' + str(counter))


    response = input("Do you want to play again (y/n)?").strip().lower()
    if response not in ('', 'y', 'yes'):
        play_again = False
```

Comment: for some reason it seems to keep repeating the first few lines over and over. I edited the code above to show you

Comment: @rhys1619 which code block are you running? The first or the second?

Comment: second. the code above is what i did if you need to check

Comment: its still repeating over and over

Comment: Alright, so a few things were causing bugs and I fixed them as well as reworked your code slightly so that the counter method would work better. The main issue was indenting, some parts which should have been indented weren't and vice versa. I will paste the new and fully working code into my answer.

Comment: OMG it works. thank you sooooo much ive been trying to make this work for hours.  You are amazing

Comment: @rhys1619 before you go make sure to mark my answer as, well, the answer so that others may visually see that this question has been solved